# Kendo MVC Grid Validation change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC grid.and i need to change the default validation message of the time picker.

When i put the wrong time like 08:67 then it shows the error message "**The News Date Must be a Date**" and i need to change thatone to "**Please Enter Correct Time**"

### Time Picker

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.NewsTime).Title("News Time").Format("{0:HH:mm}").Width(60);
```

I've already tried it using Data Annotation to do.

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime NewsDate{ get; set; }
```

How can i change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TimeSpan` datatype instead of `DateTime`

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan Monday { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Time")]

public DateTime NewsDate{ get; set; }
```